# Permutation with optimal payoff

Tags: probability, permutations, expectation, combinatorial-game-theory

You play a game as follows. You have $N$ coins in front of you. For each coin you know:

- the probability to get "heads" $p_i$
- the prize $r_i$ you get when you get "heads" (as money)

The rules are:

- choose a coin
- if you get heads, you're done, you get the prize and the game stops.
- otherwise you can choose and flip another coin (you can't flip twice the same coin).
- and so on until you get heads or you reach a limit of $K$ flips ($K\leq N)$.

You want to find the best strategy: the one with highest expected payoff. Some simple cases:

- For $K=N$ the solution is just ordering by decreasing $r_i$ ($p_i$ does not matter).
- For $K=1$ the solution is just choosing the coin with highest expected payoff $p_ir_i$.

For $1<K<N$, it doesn't seem to be that simple. One solution is brute force: compute expected payoff for all partial permutations.

Do you see an (algorithmically) better solution?

Comment: I may be wrong but why not compute the products $p_ir_i$ and order the elements that way, and then choose elements in descending order?

Comment: Oh never mind I realize my mistake. The expectation values of second-and-onward flips depend on the first probability (because if the first coin is heads, we dont reach the latter coins and their values)

Comment: Yep :-). The case $K=N$ is an extreme counter-example against ordering by expected payoff.

Comment: Even for $K=2$ I don't see how to do it without computing.  That is, looking at examples, I don't see a simple way to "read off" the answer by inspection.

Comment: I did some brute-force calculations just to see what expressions look like. Start off with $p_ir_i$ and go for another coin, so your total expectation is $p_ir_i + (1-p_i)p_jr_j = (p_ir_i + p_jr_j) - (p_ip_j)r_j$. In general, each set of flips will have the "naïve sum" of all expectations, minus "coupling terms" that look like the $(\prod_{n=1}^{k}p_n)r_k$ for each $k \in (1...# of flips)$. This convinces me that brute-force computation is the best solution, but since the coupling terms do kind of depend on the easily-calculable terms, perhaps I am wrong...

Answer (score 0):

This still takes exponential time and probably qualifies as "brute force", but it's better than your suggestion (computing expected payoff for all partial permutations): Compute the expected payoff for all subgames with more than $N-K$ coins left (choosing coins by comparing the subgames with one fewer coin left). For instance, for $K=N$, this takes $O\left(2^N\right)$ time, instead of $O(N!)$ for the permutations.